# Difference between direct plotting and using function to plot

Tags: plotting

Edit: Syed's and Lukas's suggestions both solve this problem, thank you very much.

I'm having some issues with a set of plots I'm making (it's to do with Penrose diagrams, but that's probably not of importance). Specifically, I input

```
transformation = {Tan[X + T] == x + t, Tan[X - T] == x - t};
solveforXT = Solve[transformation, {X, T}, Reals][[2]] /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0};
XTvec = {X, T} /. solveforXT
```

which outputs

```
Out[*]= {1/2 (-ArcTan[t - x] + ArcTan[t + x]),1/2 (ArcTan[t - x] + ArcTan[t + x])}
```

Then, I use `ParametricPlot` to draw some graphs. First, I plot

```
ParametricPlot[{XTvec /. {t -> -inf},  XTvec /. {t -> inf}}, {x, -Inf, Inf},  PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}},  PlotStyle -> {Black}]
```

where `inf` and `Inf` are just numbers, 10^2 and 10^3 respectively, which make the plot look the way I want it. Indeed, this outputs a figure,
[image: The plot, the way I want it.]

which is exactly the figure I want to end up with, but if I do all my plots in this manner, it will get unreadable fast. So I define a function,

```
Curve[t0_, x0_] := XTvec /. {t -> t0, x -> x0}
```

which, in my head, will do the exact same thing as the above. So then I write the exact same command as before, but with the `Curve` function in it,

```
ParametricPlot[{Curve[-inf, x], Curve[inf, x]}, {x, -Inf, Inf},  PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}},  PlotStyle -> {Black}]
```

[image: The figure drawn with a function, which suddenly has holes in it.]

But suddenly, the graph is no longer complete. It has big holes in it. Nothing I do seems to change this; I can reduce the size of `Inf` compared to `inf` which will reduce the size of the holes somewhat, but nothing I do gets rid of the holes completely. What is causing this?

If it matters: I'm using Mathematica 13.2.

Comment: Adding `Exclusions -> None` would fix it.

Comment: Not sure yet why it's different, but `MaxRecursion -> 15` fixes it

Comment: It has to do with resolution. Your curve has has a large region where the derivative is nearly zero and a small region where the derivative is hugh. Now it depends on how the curve is sampled. If it is sampled at evenly distributed point, the chance is high that  the small region is missed. Therefore, ParametricPlot seems to use different method for sampling in both cases.

Comment: Thank you all! Both Lukas's and Syed's suggestions work, and I very much appreciate Daniel's explanation on why it doesn't work.